# NullReferenceException when returning large amount of records to Gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ldap, nullreferenceexception

I am currently searching the AD using givenName* and sn*. The following code works only when the results are small. It does not work when the results are rather large. I am not understanding why a null reference is returned.

```
            DataTable userTable = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                searchUser.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(&(givenName=" + FirstName.Text.Trim() + "*)(sn=" + LastName.Text.Trim() + "*)))";
               // searchUser.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new String[] { "displayName", "extensionAttribute13", "description" });
                searchUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
                searchUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute13");
                searchUser.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
                SearchResultCollection multipleResults = searchUser.FindAll();


                userTable.Columns.Add("Name",System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                userTable.Columns.Add("Gentiva ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                userTable.Columns.Add("Location", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

                foreach (SearchResult result in multipleResults)
                {

                    DataRow dr = userTable.NewRow();
                    DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties != null)
                    {
                        if(result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value==null)
                        {
                            dr["Name"] = " ";
                            // MessageBox.Show("Null Hit - display");
                        }
                        else if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Name"] = (string)de.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();

                        }           
                        if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["extensionAttribute"].Value == null)
                        {
                            dr["Gentiva ID"] = " ";
                           // MessageBox.Show("Null Hit - extensions");
                        }
                        else if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["extensionAttribute"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Gentiva ID"] = (string)de.Properties["extensionAttribute"].Value.ToString();

                        }  
                        if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value == null)
                        {
                            dr["Location"] = " ";
                            // MessageBox.Show("Null Hit - description");
                        }
                        else if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Location"] = (string)de.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();

                        }

                        userTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                        de.Close();
                        de.Dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // MessageBox.Show("Null Hit");                               

                    }

                }
                grdviewMultiple.ItemsSource = userTable.AsDataView();
                grdviewMultiple.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code.. or did you just run it and go..? put some break points in the code and also how come you are not using the gridviewMultiple's DataSource propery and then you would need to Bind the data to the gridview..

Comment: also in the lines where you are adding here for example `userTable.Columns.Add("Name")` you should define datatype for a string you would do something like this 
`userTable.Columns.Add("Name",System.Type.GetType("System.String");`
what if your string fields are returning null from the de.Properties...then how can you convert `null to value.ToString` ?
Don't assume that you will always return non null values.. so a quick fix would be to some inline code that would set the string values to string.Empty or `""` if the values are null or you could add if statements

Comment: you could do something like this as well 
`dr["Location"] = (string)de.Properties["description"] ?? string.Empty;` 
this line I would definitely cast as an int dr["Gentiva ID"] = `de.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value.ToString();` like the same thing `dr["Gentiva ID"] = (int)de.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value;` when I see `ID` I think Integer so not sure why you would do .ToString() give these things a try and let me know if you understand or not

Comment: Unfortunately I can not step through the code due to it being within a VM that is not part of the domain. I changed the code to reflect your suggestion of System.Type.GetType("System.String") and get the same error. This is only when the results are large. I think I understand where you are coming from. Because it is a large result it might be returning a null reference. I thought that would of been taken care of because the value is set to a string. And all these properties that I am pulling are DirectoryStrings.

Comment: did you add the Binding portion

Comment: I think that you need to add some conditional checks then somewhere you are trying to convert a string to a null that is my guess you should check if the value is Null and you are wanting that row added to the DataTable and it's a string ..then set the value or dr["whatever column"] = string.empty

Comment: I think I see your one other issue `de.Close();` after that do 
`de.Dispose()`

Comment: I agree with DJ KRAZE. The issue is unlikely to be caused by the size of the result set but rather that the larger result set is including a record that doesn't have a value set for one of the properties and the .ToString() is being used on a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following just copy paste this into what you have and make sure you debug it..
Large data has actually nothing to do with your problem in my opinion I think that you are not doing proper checks and or conversion of types and you are getting an error

```
try
{
    searchUser.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(&(givenName=" + FirstName.Text.Trim() + "*)(sn=" + LastName.Text.Trim() + "*)))";
    searchUser.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new String[] { "displayName", "extensionAttribute13", "description" });

    SearchResultCollection multipleResults = searchUser.FindAll();
    DataTable userTable = new DataTable();

    userTable.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    userTable.Columns.Add("Gentiva ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    userTable.Columns.Add("Location", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

    foreach (SearchResult result in multipleResults)
    {
        DataRow dr = userTable.NewRow();
        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties != null)
        {
            if(result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value==null)
            {
                dr["Name"] = "";
            }
            else
            {
              dr["Name"] = (string)de.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();
            }           
            if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["extensionAttribute"].Value == null)
            {
                dr["Gentiva ID"] = DBNull.Value; 
            }
            else
            {
                dr["Gentiva ID"] = (int)de.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value;
            }
            if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value == null)
            {
                dr["Location"] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                dr["Location"] = (string)de.Properties["description"].Value.ToString();
            }

        }       
        userTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    de.Close();
    de.Dispose();
    grdviewMultiple.ItemsSource = userTable.AsDataView();
    grdviewMultiple.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
catch(ActiveDirectoryOperationException adEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show(adEx.ToString());
    de.Close();
    de.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Where I have System.Type.GetType you can also replace that with `typeof(int)` where iInt32 is and `typeof(string)` where the strings are .. can you test that code in a console application have you tried doing that locally

Comment: The current code is what I have above. I am unable to use databind. I am rather new to WPF. But it appears that it is not available that is why I have to take the datasource route. still same error. This error only happends on the domain computer. The local VM doesnt throw an exception. But then again, it is not pulling any data.

Comment: not a problem you didn't state that this was a wpf application I thought it was a windows form app sorry..

Comment: That's my fault I should of put that in the title. I just added a tag. Thanks for your help

Comment: did you add any conditional check can you show the updated code in your original question.. there is something you must be doing incorrectly and or missing I would love to see what the updated code looks like

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the stacktrace?

Comment: The error I get is System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Now, when I use the message boxes to step through it in a way (because it is created off of the domain) I do get a null reference returned. I set the value to String.Empty (above) and it still throws the same exception.

Comment: you have an Object reference not initialized properly how many places is this object used..? `userTable` I would try moving this outside of the method `userTable` Declaring it as a public static like this at the class level `DataTable userTable = new DataTable(); then where you have this line `DataTable userTable = new DataTable();` I would check to see if the object == null if so then use this line again `DataTable userTable = new DataTable();`

Comment: which one of the Messagebox lines throws the error..??
you need to wrap all of those if statements with an else.. 
dr["Name"] = (string)de.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();
                            dr["Gentiva ID"] = (string)de.Properties["extensionAttribute13"].Value.ToString();
                            dr["Location"] = (string)de.Properties["description"].Value.ToString();
but these in the else of the appropriate if statement

Comment: Its the "Location" that returns null

Comment: wrap the code around an if{}else{} assign the `dr{"Location"] = ""` in the else portion of your code if the value is null

Comment: you're if condition / assignment is incorrect.. you want to set the datarow = ""; I will fix the code and post an edit for you that should do the trick.

Comment: That worked... thank you so much for your patience and help. If I could mark the correct answer 2x I would

Comment: not a problem.. I notice something else you could also change to make your code more readable use this because you are already able to get at the properties 
`if(result.Properties["displayname"].Value==null)` instead of the `if(result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value==null)` now that I have it working for you.. just try to refactor where you can when you can.